Is there a type of reduction that independently transforms different parts of an instance?
Is there some notion of a poly-time reduction that maps certain different parts of the instance independently, i.e., $f((x,y))\mapsto(f_1(x),f_2(y))$ where $(x,y)\in L\iff (f_1(x),f_2(y))\in L'$?

You just defined such a notion, so the answer is trivially yes.  I'm not sure what more there is to say, or what your real question is.  Do you have a specific question about this notion?

@D.W. Has anyone proved the existence of such a reduction between specific or (preferably) general NP-complete problems? Has anyone else written about or discussed such a notion? I'd appreciate any resources you can recommend if so please

@D.W. Or if you or anyone else just has any thoughts about the notion in general, for example, if you have some reason to believe that such a reduction would not exist between general NP-complete problems. I am hopeful that this reduction exists between general NP-complete problems and will take any insight you can provide.
